# How to get results form async/await callback function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use the GCP client api to get list of folders inside a bucket.

I have a function such as below:

```
export async function getTritonModels(bucketName, path) {
  try {
    let models = null;
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
    models = await bucket.getFiles(query, (err, files, nextQuery, apiResponse) => {
      return [...apiResponse?.prefixes]
    });

    console.log("models:", models)

  } catch (err) {
    return []
  }
}
```

This is still returning `null` for models - how can I set the models value inside the callback function?

Comment: `bucket.getFiles` is not a promise. It uses a callback, so sticking await in front won't do anything (anything helpful at least)

Comment: You need to make a promise that you can `await`.